# SQL calculate growth percent from datatable

Tags: sql-server

I have following datatable in SQL Server 2012 DB:

```
DATE          TICKER    PRICE
2015-09-25      A         10
2015-09-24      A         9
2015-09-23      A         8
2015-09-25      B         3
2015-09-24      B         4
2015-09-23      B         5
```

And I want to select following values with sql query:

```
TICKER   VALUE
 A       1.25
 B       0.6
```

Where value for ticker A is 10 / 8 (Newest Date and specific date which is in this example 2015-09-23 and it should be changeable).

Value for ticker B is 3 / 5.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TICKER, 
ROUND(
((SELECT PRICE FROM INDICEPRICEHISTORY WHERE TICKER = 'A' AND EOD =  '2015-09-25') /
(SELECT PRICE FROM INDICEPRICEHISTORY WHERE TICKER = 'A' AND EOD = '2015-09-23')),2)
AS VALUE
FROM INDICEPRICEHISTORY
```

So what I at least need to do is get the WHERE TICKER = 'A' to be relative to the actual ticker selected.. and ALSO EOD's (EOD = DATE) to be variable..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is important to show us what you have tried. We are here to help, but not to provide complete answers for some specific problems.

Comment: Hi, I really don't know even where to start as I'm not quite familiar with SQL and just need this one task to be done in DB-side.. But I understand your point and this forum is my last my chance for this until I have to find someone else to do this task for me.... Thank you for your comment and have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`first_value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) and [`last_value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx) to get the first and last prices per tracker, respectively. From there on, it's just math:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [tracker], 
       LAST_VALUE([price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [tracker] 
                                 ORDER BY [date]
                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND
                                              UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) /
       FIRST_VALUE([price]) OVER (PARTITION BY [tracker] 
                                  ORDER BY [date]  
                                  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
                                               UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
       AS [Growth]                                
FROM   mytable
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a833/1/0)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to get the last price, the do a join to the price on the date you are looking for:

```
;WITH
    LastPrice
    (
        SELECT      Ticker, Price,
                    RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ticker ORDER BY EOD DESC)
        FROM        INDICEPRICEHISTORY
    )

SELECT      I.Ticker,
            Value = L.Price / I.Price
FROM        INDICEPRICEHISTORY  I
INNER JOIN  LastPrice           L ON I.Ticker = L.Ticker
WHERE       I.EOD = '2015-09-23' AND L.RowNumber = 1
```